# Mutating value in a React state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel really stupid for asking such a simple question like this, but for some reason I forgot how to change the value in a React state object. For example:

```
const initialState = {
   likes: 100,
   dislikes: 25,
   isLiked: false,
   isDisliked: false
}

const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

const handleLikes = e => {
    if (data.isLiked) {
        setData({ ...data, likes: data.likes - 1 });
    } else {
        setData({ ...data, likes: data.likes + 1 });
    }

    setData({ ...data, isLiked: !data.isLiked })
}

<button className={`like-button ${data.isLiked ? 'liked' : ''}`} onClick={handleLikes}>Like | <span className='likes-counter'>{data.likes}</span></button>
```

The confusing part, the part that made me ask this question, is the **likes: data.likes + 1** part. When I click the button, it adds/removes the className as intended, but the value never changes. I know this is such a simple thing but I have spent a while on this.

What is wrong with the **likes: data.likes + 1**?

**Edit**:
This edit is for anyone who might have a similar question in the future. The simple answer is, if you update the state twice like so:

```
number = 0
setNumber(number + 1)
setNumber(number + 1)
```

You would expect number to be 2, but it will be 1. During both the first and second execution, number is equal to 0 (because the update will only happen during the next re-render).

However, with

```
setNumber(prevNumber => prevNumber + 1)
setNumber(prevNumber => prevNumber + 1)
```

Then the result will be 2, because at every execution, react will work with the most up-to-date value.

**TLDR** if the new value depends on the previous value, use the `prevState`. Otherwise, just set the new state directly

Answer (score 2):

The two subsequent `setData` calls end up "overwriting" each other since the `data` captured by your `handleLikes` will not have changed after you call `setData`.

You'll want to use [the functional form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to be able to reliably look at the current value (even when asynchronous modifications are in queue, then return a new value based on it:

```
const handleToggleLikes = (e) => {
  setData((data) =>
    data.isLiked
      ? { ...data, likes: data.likes - 1 }
      : { ...data, likes: data.likes + 1 },
  );
  setData((data) => ({ ...data, isLiked: !data.isLiked }));
};
```

You can do both of these modifications in one invocation:

```
const handleToggleLike = e => {
    setData(data => ({
        ...data,
        likes: data.likes + (data.isLiked ? -1 : 1),  // decrease if previously liked
        isLiked: !data.isLiked,
    }));
}
```

Comment: What is interesting is when I used class component using this.setState instead of functional component, it worked just fine.

Is there a simpler way of doing it, or is it the only solution?

Comment: Yes, because class components' `setState` always merges changes, it doesn't replace the full state. You could also use separate state atoms here for similar behavior: `setLikes(...); setIsLiked(...);`

Comment: Hi @AKX, I tried your code in sandbox to see how that like condition responded and it changed the count from 100 to 1. I had to modify it like `likes: data.isLiked ? data.likes - 1 : data.likes + 1,  // decrease if previously liked`. Is this something happening there only or locally too?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi the example is just missing some parantheses, it should've been `likes: data.likes + (data.isLiked ? -1 : 1)`

Comment: @IronGeek Good catch, edited.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use a setState function to update the state object:

1. Pass it the new state object (which is what you are doing in your code)
2. Pass it a callback function that takes the current state object as argument, uses it to create the new state object, and returns the new state object.

Whenever you want to use the current state object to create a new state object, you must use the second way. In your case, your code:

```
setData({...data, likes: data.likes - 1})
```

uses the current state object (data) to create the new state object. So you must use a callback instead, like this:

```
setData((cur_data)=>({...cur_data, likes: cur_data.likes-1}))
```

Note that I am using the arrow syntax in the callback function to return the new state object.

Comment: I changed my code to match your suggestion, but it is still not working

setData(prevData => ({...prevData, likes: prevData.likes + 1}))